# Galleria & LightBox IE7 & IE8 css issue

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, galleria

I am using version Galleria 1.2, which I know is a bit out of date, and I am having issues with IE7 and IE8. FireFox works correctly. I tried to upgrade to 1.2.2 but ran into other issues which I will have to deal with later due to time constraints.

The problem is that the background of the lightbox opens up black instead of 50% opacity. If I click on the image a second time, the lightbox opens up correctly.

First click:

[image]

Second click:

[image]

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/content/js/galleria.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">Galleria.loadTheme('~/content/css/Galleria/galleria.classic.js');</script>


$('#imageGallery').galleria({ 
    debug: true,
    width: 300,
    height: 225,
    showInfo: false,
    showCounter: false,
    showImagenav: false,
    data_source: data,
    on_image: function(image, thumb) {
        var gallery = this;
        $(image).click( function() {
            gallery.openLightbox();

            });
            }

});
```

Here's the page request using Fiddler which seems to show the css file being loaded:

[image]

If I load the css myself prior to the component loading, I get this:

[image]

I am not sure how to fix it.

Thank you!

Comment: If someone answers this without any example code i'd be impressed.

Comment: Good point. The only thing is that I am using their css files out of the box with no changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest version of Galleria fixed this issue. However, it introduced some new ones. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the `<script type="text/javascript" src="~/content/js/galleria.js"></script>` after the CSS is already loaded.

Comment: I am not loading the css file explicitly. Should I be?

Comment: what is happening (i think) is that the javascript is being initiated without the CSS as it is loaded in second. That would explain why the CSS value is applied AFTER the first click.

You don't have to load it explicitly as is being applied.

Comment: I added a Fiddler screenshot which seems to say that the css file is being loaded at least from FireFox. The fiddler dump from IE is a bit different. I'll have to dig a bit deeper tomorrow. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I know the CSS is being loaded, I'm saying that it is being loaded second.

Comment: I tried to load the css prior to galleria.js loading. The page gets pretty hosed in both IE and FF. I'll post an image so you can see.